# stop windows service in onStart() method

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to stop windows service in `onStart()` method when customer doesn't have a license. I use `service.Stop()`, but it does not work.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("new OnStart");
        if (LicenseValidetor.ValidCountAndTypeDevices())
        {
            WsInitializeBridge();
        }
        else
        {
            service = new ServiceController("BridgeService");
            service.Stop();
            _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("LicenseValidetor Error");
        }
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("end Start");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("error In onstart method ");
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `service`?  And are you sure that the line of code is being hit?

Comment: Um. If it's the same service as you're running in, then simply exiting the `OnStart` method without leaving any other threads running will stop the service.

Comment: Are you doing This Remotely? Or from the Client machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot stop a service from within the `OnStart` method of that same service.

The [`ServiceController.Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx) method internally calls [`ControlService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or it's `Ex` counterpart). Notice that one of the reasons that this function can fail is:

> **ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL**
>   The requested control code cannot be sent to the service because the state of the service is **SERVICE_STOPPED**, **SERVICE_START_PENDING**, or **SERVICE_STOP_PENDING**.

Well, guess what - when you're inside your `OnStart` method, the state of your service is `SERVICE_START_PENDING`.

---

The correct way to cope with this situation is to signal any other threads that you may have started to have them exit, and then to exit your `OnStart` method. The service control manager will notice that the process has exited and revert your service status to `SERVICE_STOPPED`. It may also notify an interactive user that "The service started and then stopped" or words to that effect.

Comment: Hi. Could you expand on the "signal any other threads" comment? If I am running a service (with TopShelf in my case), I would have thought my program's thread is the only thread running. Why would other "threads" be running? Thanks

Comment: @Fandango68 - that sentence continues with "that you may have started". So if you haven't started any other threads, you can ignore that sentence. Note that it's not all that uncommon for services to run multiple threads and the point here is that if you leave any other (foreground) threads running, the service won't be considered to be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that "simply not starting any workers" may not work (or perhaps I am being just plain stupid ;) ).

I built a service, with a try/catch(all) around my OnStart code. Because of a missing line in my .config file it crashed with an IOException, before it started any worker thread. The exception skipped over my thread starters. No thread was started by my code. Honestly.

But the service DID NOT STOP. I don't know why. As a desperate measure, I rethrew the exception, that helped.

I am still wondering if the file system watcher threads in Enterprise Library configuration were the problem. EntLib is woven to deeply into my code to remove it as an experiment, so I did not investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains why what you are doing doesn't work but doesn't offer a good solution.

There are a couple of things your code isn't doing that it should.

1. Set the `.ExitCode` to indicate that your service is in an error state.
2. Throw an exception. Not having a license is exceptional. Throw it.

EXAMPLE:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("new OnStart");
    try
    {        
        if (LicenseValidetor.ValidCountAndTypeDevices())
        {
            WsInitializeBridge();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("LicenseValidetor Error");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.ExitCode = e.HResult
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry($"error In onstart method: {e.Message}");
        throw
    }

    _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("end Start");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that your not waiting to ensure that the Service has actually stopped or if it is even running in the first instance.

Do this :-

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("new OnStart");
        if (LicenseValidetor.ValidCountAndTypeDevices())
        {
            WsInitializeBridge();
        }
        else
        {
            int time = 10000;

            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);

            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

            _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("LicenseValidetor Error");
        }
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("end Start");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _bridgeServiceEventLog.WriteEntry("error In onstart method ");
    }
}
```