# How to stop a .NET written windows service from within itself?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-services

I have seen a number of similar questions on the forum without much of a clear solution example or popular agreed answer. In my .NET written windows service, In OnStart method, I am performing some validations (i.e. licensing, data source connection, etc.). If any of these requirements fail, I would like to force stop the service. I have a number of questions: Is stopping the service when validations fail a proper approach? If yes, what is wrong with my code below? If no, then how should I deal with the scenario?

UPDATE: After @madreflection comments, I updated the code and then installed the service. When attempting to manually start it, it starts and stops as intended.

```
private readonly System.Threading.TimerCallback _delegate = SampleWindowsServiceEventAction;
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (!DoAllValidations())    
        Stop();
    else
        _timer = new Timer(_delegate, this, 0, PollingInterval);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _timer?.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Just call [Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop).

Comment: @madreflection I have tried that, however, the debugger does not stop. Is that expected?

Comment: `Stop` doesn't stop the debugger. It sends a control signal to the Service Control Manager to terminate the service, which will eventually call `OnStop`, but `OnStart` has to return, first. Because it's still in startup at that point, it can't stop immediately.

Comment: Ok, couple of observations here. I read in a different thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068492/stop-windows-service-in-onstart-method) that service should not be stopped within OnStart method but rather one needs to ensure all dependent threads are terminated and that's all?
Also in my `StopService()` method, I get a "service was not found" error. Is it because in debug mode, the service control manager does not really recognize it?

Comment: That's not the same thing. It's using `ServiceController` to stop it. You should call the `Stop` method in `ServiceBase`, which I linked. The SCM doesn't know what threads are part of your service, so if all threads terminate without calling `Stop`, the service stays "running" with no code actually active. Calling `Stop` (not `controller.Stop`) is the corrrect way to end the service gracefully if `OnStart` determines that it shouldn't be running.

Comment: Works as expected now. The service does not even start as intended. Thank you!

Comment: That error message means that `OnStart` or `OnStop` is taking more than 30 seconds. What's `DoAllValidations` doing? Also, if you call `Stop` in that branch, `_timer` will be `null` because it never reaches the branch that assigns it, so `OnStop` needs to account for that. If it doesn't, it won't log on the next line. A try/catch should only be relied on for exceptional cases; a `null` there is not exceptional.

Comment: Not sure if I understood. `DoAllValidations` mainly set the connectionstring and ensure the data source is accessible and checks for some shared network paths and ensures they are accessible as well. In the `OnStop` method, I am disposing the _timer. Does it not suffice?

Comment: Frist, if `_timer` is `null` because you called `Stop` instead of assigning it, then `(null).Dispose()` will throw `NullReferenceException`. I'm saying that it should be `_timer?.Dispose()`. Second, those checks may be taking too long.

Comment: Ok, got it. Is there a way to increase the 30 seconds wait time?

Comment: Yes, but unless you're talking to a satellite on Mars, you shouldn't need longer. You should address what's causing your code to run so long.